# Huxtable package for R: Problems with using set_background_color()

Tags: r

I tried to colorize certain cells in a data frame (df_data) as highlighted below:
[image: DATAFRAME_with_highlights]

Inspired by the [Introduction to Huxtable](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html) I tried the following:

```
library(huxtable)
as_hux(df_table)                                                  %>%
 set_background_color(where(df_table["choice_mean"] < 2), 'red')  %>%
 set_background_color(where(df_table["N"] > 110), 'yellow')
```

The above commands colored the cells in the correct row – but only in the first column instead of the desired columns (N, choice_mean)/ the respective cells:

[image: HUXTABLE_with_highlights]

Many thanks for a brief reply and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `where(DF_table["choice_mean"] < 2)`.

Here's what's going on, with some data so others can reproduce the problem (hint hint):

```
DF_table <- data.frame(choice_mean = c(1,2,3,1,3), N = c(100, 120, 100, 90, 100))
where(DF_table["choice_mean"] < 2)
##     row col
## [1,]   1   1
## [2,]   4   1
```

You've only passed in part of the data frame to `where`, and it correctly tells you that in that (1-column) part of the data frame, row 1 col 1 and row 4 col 1 are less than 2. This then gives the wrong info to `set_background_color`.

You can get round this by using standard R subsetting:

```
DF_table <- as_hux(DF_table)
set_background_color(DF_table, DF_table$choice_mean < 2, 'choice_mean', 'red')
set_background_color(DF_table, DF_table$N > 110, 'N', 'yellow')
```

Here, `DF_table$N > 110` specifies the rows, and `'N'` the column.

This is just the same as normal R subsetting:

```
DF_table[DF_table$N > 110, 'N']
## 120
```

Comment: Thank you so much David, very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Any idea why the order of commands in the pipe chain matters? For example the following throws an error:
`DF_table <- data.frame(choice_mean = c(1,2,3,1,3), N = c(100, 120, 100, 90, 100))
as_hux(DF_table) %>%
  add_colnames() %>% 
  set_background_color(DF_table$N > 110, 'N', 'yellow')`
while this works fine (add_colnames at end):
`as_hux(DF_table) %>%
  set_background_color(DF_table$N > 110, 'N', 'yellow') %>% 
  add_colnames()`
Error message is: "Error in `[<-` (`* tmp *`, rc $ row, rc $ col, value = value): out of bounds indexing"

Comment: That's a new question, but presumably because `add_colnames` adds the names to the table, and you then try to compare the column name itself (`"N"`) to 110, and that barfs.

Comment: @dash2 in a regression table made with `huxreg()` for a *list of models*, is it possible to colorize table elements *conditionally on the model*? I am looking for a way to quickly spot differences between 2 lists of models (*list_models* & *list_models_adjusted*) and am thinking of sth. like "`huxreg(list_models_adjusted) %>% 
  set_background_color(where(list_models_adjusted[[ANY MODEL]][["p.value"]] <  list_models[[ANY MODEL]][["p.value"]]), 'orange')`". Would you know of any fix? many thanks!

Comment: This is another new question - why not ask it as such?

Comment: @dash2 voila: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758677/huxtable-package-for-r-color-coding-differences-between-two-lists-of-models-in